# Will the refactor happens to all the classes, when we merge or branches to master using git

Tags: java, git, merge, refactoring

Let's say if we have 2 different class files being refactored by 2 different people. And they don't refactor rename to the methods and classes related to the other class. The refactored code is pushed to their respective branches and when they merge it to master will the codes get renamed by themselves in the master repository? I'm new to git and I think it's impossible please explain me if it is possible or not?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "will the code get renamed by themselves in the master repository"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The refactored code is pushed to their respective branches and when they merge it to master will the codes get renamed by themselves in the master repository?

When you merge the code from branch A into branch B, branch B now has the commits (and thus, changes) made in branch A. So say you have a branch called `branch1`. When you merge that into `master`, any of the changes made in `branch1` will then be a part of `master`. This is the key idea of git: you make changes on separate branches and merge them together when you're done. The most functional copy (generally `master`) contains a fusion of the changes from different branches all merged together.

However, if you're wondering if git does any sort of refactoring in that it will rename classes in files you didn't modify like some sort of IDE might, then no, this is not within scope of what git does. Like if you have a class `Apple` that is referenced in `Fruits.java`, and you change the `Apple` class to be `Banana`, git won't modify other files like `Fruits.java` for you.